# Split based by a-z character in an alphanumeric string in python

Tags: python

I have strings like "5d4h2s", where I want to get 5, 4, and 2 from that string, but I also want to know that 5 was paired with d, and that 4 was paired with h, etc etc. Is there an easy way of doing this without parsing char by char?

Comment: Do you have any more complicated inputs? Or do they always come in pairs?

Comment: Put another way, is 10d4h20s a valid input?

Comment: This is basically a notation of time. Valid inputs can be 10d5h10m25s, 10m, 5h25s, 10d5m, etc.

Comment: You don't mention real-world things like checking that the string is in correct format, nor imposing the reasonable restrictions (1) that the components appear in dhms order and (2) that the numbers of hms are less than 24,60,60 respectively when they are the 2nd or subsequent component... is this homework?

Comment: It is not homework. It's for an SMS app where text space is limited and I want a short, easy to read and understand annotation.

Comment: So what do you do with syntactically incorrect input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your input does not get more complicated than `5d4h2s`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "5d4h2s"
>>> p = re.compile("([0-9])([a-z])")
>>> for m in p.findall(s):
...   print m
... 
('5', 'd')
('4', 'h')
('2', 's')
```

And if it gets, you can easily adjust the regular expression, e.g.

```
>>> p = re.compile("([0-9]*)([a-z])")
```

to accept input like:

```
>>> s = "5d14h2s"
```

Finally, you can condense the regex to:

```
>>> p = re.compile("([\d]+)([dhms])")
```

Comment: I wonder which of these is faster; I was tempted to use regular expressions but generally don't if I don't have to, but I'm sure the double list comprehension isn't particularly swift either

Comment: mmh, just benchmarked it; with a precompiled pattern, the regex is actually a bit faster .. see this gist: http://gist.github.com/421540

Comment: You could use \d and \d+ in place of the [0-9] and[0-9]*.

Answer (score 0):

For time string, you can try the following:

```
m = re.match("(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?", "5d4h2s")
print m.group(1) # Days
print m.group(2) # Hours
print m.group(3) # Minutes
print m.group(4) # Seconds
print int(m.group(1)[:-1]) # Days, number
```